# Tkinter file does not takes string from a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have made three different files, 1st file(home.py) the main one calls (ckbc.py), this second file processes and sends string to third file (dataIO).

```
# home.py
def find1():
    d1=desentry1.get()
    dataIO.takeentry(d1,None,None,None)
    ckbc.to1()
    desentry1.delete(0,END)
    # ov1=StringVar()
    ov1=dataIO.valueout()[0]
    # print(vv1)
    desentry1.insert(0,ov1)
```

this is the first file which has to take input of string. from ckbc.py but apparently it does not take the value directly from ckbc so i made this dataio file.

```
# dataio.py
def valueentry(v1, v2, v3, v4):
    global t1, t2, t3, t4
    t1 = v1
    # print(t1)
    t2 = v2
    t3 = v3
    t4 = v4
    return t1

def valueout():
    tt1 = t1
    tt2 = t2
    tt3 = t3
    tt4 = t4
    print(tt1)
    return tt1,tt2,tt3,tt4
```

now when i call valueout in home.py it says t1 may be undefined. also print t1 command works fine but print tt1 gives no output.
this is ckbc file.

```
def get_button_text1(button_id):
    # global vv1
    """Function to retrieve text of a button with a given identifier"""
    # print(ubtn)
    btn_text = ubtn1[button_id]['text']
    dataIO.valueentry(btn_text, None, None, None)
    # top1.destroy()
    # print(btn_text)  
def to1():
    global top1
    top1 = Toplevel()
    string_list = []  # empty list to store the strings
    c = dataIO.senddata()[0]
    a = str(c)
    # print(a)
    b = ""
    if a.startswith("UC") or a.startswith("uc") or a.startswith("nibp"):
        a = a.upper()
    else:
        a = a.capitalize()
    b = a
    # print(b)
    search_words = b.split()
    i = 0
    with open("materialcode.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    # key = k.upper()

    for line in lines:
        # if word in key:

        for word in search_words:
            if word in line:
                global buttons
                # print(line)
                buttons = {}

                string_name = f"string1_{i + 1}"  # create a variable name with a unique number
                string_value = f"{line}"  # create the string value
                locals()[string_name] = string_value  # dynamically create the variable and assign the string value
                string_list.append(locals()[string_name])  # add the variable to the list
                button_text = locals()[f"string1_{i + 1}"]  # create the text for the button
                button = ttk.Button(top1, text=button_text, command=lambda button_id=i: get_button_text1(
                    button_id))  # create the button with the text
                button.pack()  # add the button to the GUI
                buttons[i] = button
                # print(button)
                ubtn1.update(buttons)
                i += 1
                break
    # print(string_list)
```

I basically want the btn_text variable's string value to come inside ov1 variable in home.py

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details. Also edit the question for correct English.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.  Does it mean that the value of `ov1` is not what you expect? Is what you want the value of `ov1` the value of `d1`?

Comment: @acw1668 ov1 wants to get  the value of btn_text

Comment: Then you need to exit `ckbc.to1()` only until one of the buttons is clicked.  Currently `ckbc.to1()` will exit without pressing any button, and so you cannot get what you want.